# two dimensional select query for sqlite db

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to generate summary table to show the count(distinct pid) for each model
I have database like:

```
model corner pid
aa  c1  1
aa  c1  1
aa  c1  2
aa  c2  3
aa  c3  4
bb  c1  1
bb  c1  1
bb  c2  2
bb  c2  3
bb  c2  3
bb  c3  4
```

the result is something like:

```
corner  aa bb
c1      2   1
c2      1   2
c3      1   1
```

may I know what query command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get the counts you want:

```
select corner, model, count(distinct pid) as n from t group by corner, model
```

which gives you this:

```
corner|model|n
c1    |aa   |2
c1    |bb   |1
c2    |aa   |1
c2    |bb   |2
c3    |aa   |1
c3    |bb   |1
```

then group that derived table by `corner` and sum the `n`s based on the `model` value:

```
select
    corner,
    sum(case when model = 'aa' then n else 0 end) as aa,
    sum(case when model = 'bb' then n else 0 end) as bb
from (
    select corner, model, count(distinct pid) as n
    from t
    group by corner, model
) dt
group by corner
```

SQLite represents booleans as 1 and 0 (for true and false respectively) so you could write that as:

```
select
    corner,
    sum(n * (model = 'aa')) as aa,
    sum(n * (model = 'bb')) as bb
from (
    select corner, model, count(distinct pid) as n
    from t
    group by corner, model
) dt
group by corner
```

but I find the portable `case` version easier to understand at a glance.

Either version produces results like:

```
corner|aa|bb
c1    |2 |1
c2    |1 |2
c3    |1 |1
```

If you want the results to come out ordered by `corner` then you should include an explicit `order by corner` on query:

```
select
    corner,
    sum(case when model = 'aa' then n else 0 end) as aa,
    sum(case when model = 'bb' then n else 0 end) as bb
from (
    select corner, model, count(distinct pid) as n
    from t
    group by corner, model
) dt
group by corner
order by corner
```